# android: How to animate and transition images between two list (or grid) views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, scene

I have two gridviews and move images between them on a touch event. I would like to have some transition to show the image moving from one view to the other. Ideally it would appear that the images move across the screen similar to the look of a drag and drop. But instead of the user dragging, I would like the image to move from one view to another on a touch event. But any transition that communicates the idea that the image has moved from one list will do.

I've looked at Scene transitions but the doc says "The framework does not support animating changes to ListView objects, so you should not try to animate them during a transition."

Any sample code from anyone that has done something similar would be appreciated or some guidance to the best approach.